# Resize Content to fit inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to create a layout which shows a graph inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and below a table with some Data. 
I want the Graph to be Fullscreen on start and then you would have to scroll to see the Data.
what i am Currently doing is the following:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context="de.glm9637.fengels.layouttest.DashboardActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="112dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode= "parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Which works fine. 
But now i want the LineChart to be resized when the toolbar collapses, so its still visible on Top. How could i archive such a effect?

Comment: `app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="1dp"` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: @Ekalips and what exactly should i do after adding this?

Comment: That's all. After this your LineChart won't disappear after toolbar collapses

Comment: @Ekalips But i Wan't the LineChart to be resized so the height always matches the AppBarLayout Size

Comment: Add `OnOffsetChangedListener` to your AppBarLayout and resize what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

           <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard"/>

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```